# Problems writing a module for phpBMS

Tags: php, mysql, class

I am trying to write a small, simple module for phpBMS.

I am basically modifying and simplifying one that exists, and have gotten to the stage of creating the table and pages in phpBMS itself and making the module installable.

I am now trying to create the php page that will allow for new records to be inserted into the table via phpBMS, and I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'guests' not found in xxx_addedit.php on line 45
```

The file is actually comments until line 40, so I have posted the first 9 lines, and line 45 corresponds to the 5th line

```
include("../../include/session.php");
include("include/tables.php");
include("include/fields.php");
include("include/menu.php");
$thetable = new xxx($db, "tbld:4e28e4bd-d4b0-1a2b-4d87-a4ddf8a54a86");
$therecord = $thetable->processAddEditPage();
if(isset($therecord["phpbmsStatus"]))
    $statusmessage = $therecord["phpbmsStatus"];
$pageTitle="xxx";
```

The original file I am modifying is viewable online in the source [here](http://www.phpbms.org/browser/trunk/phpbms/modules/base/menu_addedit.php), as well as the include files referenced.

It was my understanding that I should be able to make a new instance of the table class called whichever I like, so I am not exactly why it seems I have to define a class for each table?

Any advice here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it by modifying the include file where classes are defined.